# Failed to install DRBD9 in debian-9

Tags: debian, apt, launchpad, drbd

I need to upgrade drbd8 to drbd9. for that I following this documentation.

https://www.linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/#s-upgrading-drbd

**step 1**

```
root@oreo:~# add-apt-repository ppa:linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack

 This PPA contains DRBD9, drbd-utils, LINSTOR (client, python API, server).

This differs from official, production grade LINBIT repositories in several ways, including:
- We push RCs immediately to the PPA
- We don't push hotfixes, these usually have to wait until the next RC/release
- We only keep 2 LTS versions up to date (Bionic and Focal, but not Xenial)

For support and access to official repositories see:
https://www.linbit.com or write an email to: sales AT linbit.com
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~linbit/+archive/ubuntu/linbit-drbd9-stack
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp68jovxd3/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

**step 2** Next you will want to add the DRBD signing key to your trusted keys

```
wget -O- http://packages.linbit.com/gpg-pubkey-53B3B037-282B6E23.asc | apt-key add -
```

**step 3** Lastly perform an apt update so Debian recognizes the updated repository.

```
apt update
```

I got **error** like this

```
apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:7 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute Release
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The ppa should work only on **Ubuntu and its derivatives**.

**On debian**  to install `drbd9` you need to:

add the gpg key to your keyring:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x53B3B037282B6E23
gpg --export -a 0x53B3B037282B6E23 |sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://packages.linbit.com/<hash>/ stretch drbd-9.0
```

Where `<hash>`: is the 40-character access hash you received by email.

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install drbd9-utils
```

Comment: How to get 40-character access (Hash)? how to apply for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

That's a 404 because that path does not exist. Visit http://ppa.launchpad.net/linbit/linbit-drbd9-stack/ubuntu/dists/ to see all the available distros.

LINBIT normally only provides packages for LTS releases. While, I believe, Hirsute will be a future LTS release. It is still presently a development/future release.